# How to add Royalties to ERC1155 using ERC2981

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, erc-1155

i am trying to make an auction contract for a market place. i want to add the functionality of Royalties in my smart contract.i searc google , youtube but there is no specific or proper implementation available. is there any knows , how we can we implement this ERC1155 and ERC2981

Answer (score 0):

Reading the EIP-2981 will definitely help you: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981
In short, you will need in your smart contract to check if the contract supports the ERC-2981 interface, and call the `royaltyInfo()` function to send the royalties to the receiver.

Comment: i have read the contract that you have mention above , but the thing i am looking for is that , is there any article or youtube video available that tell me step by step of implementation of eip2981 , since i search the google , youtube i could not found anything better